# GroovyScript Name Generator

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

I'm using READYAPI! for testing purposes.  I'm currently at a road block.

*Is there a way to use a Groovy Script to Generate Random American Names?*

I've done some research online and I don't see anyway to do this with Groovy Script.

This is the closes I've come to:
https://github.com/ajbrown/name-machine

Comment: You could it then?

Comment: I'm new to ReadyAPI, not an excuse.  I just was not sure if this had been already created before I spent hours attempting to create it myself.

Comment: OK, that is seemed to be nice. You can use if you are not finished yours. Hope you know how to use that.

Comment: I don't know how to use it, but I will figure it out

Comment: Build the library as per the git repo instructions. Then copy the generated jar files(including dependencies) under READY_HOME/bin/ext directory and restart Ready API. Write the code in groovy script.